# Print star using recursion

Tags: recursion

to print pattern

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

this is correct ans

```
void recur1(int n, int i){
    //base case
    if(n==0)
        return;

    if(i==n){
        cout<<endl;
        recur1(n-1,0);
    }
     else{
         cout<<"*";
         recur1(n,i+1);
    }
}
```

but I did it like this

```
void recur1(int n, int i){
    //base case
    if(n==0)
        return;

    if(i==n){
        cout<<endl;
        recur1(n-1,0);
    }

    cout<<"*";
    recur1(n,i+1);
}
```

why we want to put recursive case in else condition, what is happening if i dont use else as it is showing segmentation fault code dump error

Comment: You already asked the same question earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72698018

Comment: I asked a different doubt in that please explain this doubt

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you do not put your recursive call `recur1(n, i + 1);` in the else branch then you will have an infinite recursion which causes the segmentation fault if `n != 0`.

For example, calling `recur1(2, 2)` allways triggers `recur1(2, 3)` which in turn triggers `recur1(2, 4)` and so on.  This will never stop.